# Multiple search with Hpricot

Tags: ruby, hpricot

Had RTFM'ed, but still puzzled. I need to get objects which satisfy at least one of the property condition list.

E.g. **divs, where class == "marked" OR class = "data" OR class = "comments"**

For now emulated it manually, but is it possible with Hpricot standard abilities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
doc = Hpricot.parse(..your data...)
divs = doc.search("//div[@class='marked' or @class='data' or @class='comments']")
```

The `search` takes an xpath expression, and xpath allows logical `and` and `or` operators. See this great answer about a similar question: [XPATH Multiple Element Filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472966/xpath-multiple-element-filters).

Comment: Thx much, had't focused on xpath :)