# XPath contains one of multiple values

Tags: xpath, filter

I have simple xpath

```
 /products/product[contains(categorie,'Kinderwagens')]
```

It works but now how do I filter on multiple categorie values

like

```
/products/product[contains(categorie,'Kinderwagens')]  +  
/products/product[contains(categorie,'Kinderwagens')]
```

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Will this work?

```
/products/product[contains(categorie,'Kinderwagens') or contains(categorie,'Wonderwagens')]
```

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472966/xpath-multiple-element-filters)

Comment: The question is about OR, isn't it?

Answer (score 21):

Do you really want contains()? Very often, people use contains() to test whether a node contains a value when they should be using "=". The difference is that if the categorie element has the string value 'Kinderwagens', then `categorie = 'wagens'` is false but `contains(categorie, 'wagens')` is true.

If you actually intended '=', then in XPath 2.0 you can write `[categorie = ('Kinderwagens', 'Wonderwagens')]`. If you're still using XPath 1.0, you need two separate comparisons with an 'or'.

Comment: Submitted [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46503195/712334) for use with attribute values.

Answer (score 8):

There are many ways:

1. `//*[contains(text(), 'Kinderwagens') or contains(text(), 'Kinderwagens')]`
2. `//product[contains(text(), 'Kinderwagens') or contains(text(), 'Kinderwagens')]`
3. `//products/product[contains(text(), 'Kinderwagens') or contains(text(), 'Kinderwagens')]`
4. `//products/product[contains(categorie, 'Kinderwagens') or contains(categorie, 'Kinderwagens')]`

Note: **| (Bitwise OR)** operator don't be use

Answer (score -3):

You can pass the multiple text as like below

```
//a[contains(text(),'JB-' | 'ABC')]
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. The xpath needs to be edited slightly like this:
`//a[contains(text(),'JB-') or contains(text(), 'ABC')]`