# Node that contains string or other string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, mechanize

I can grab a node that contains "foo", like so:

```
page.search("div.someclass td:contains('foo')")
```

How can I get a node that contains either "foo" *or* "bar". My attempts so far have failed.

I know I can do this [with XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12152890/xpath-contains-value-a-or-value-b), but I wanted to know if there is an easier solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
page.search("div.someclass td:contains('foo')", "div.someclass td:contains('bar')")
```