# XPath one of multiple attribute values with condition

Tags: html, xpath, attributes, equality

Given the following expression, how can I use `=` to be more concise and explicit?

```
(//h2/@id[contains(.,"foo") or contains(.,"bar") or contains(.,"baz"))[last()]
```

Here's what I tried, but my interpreter says it's not valid:

```
(//h2/@id[text() = ("foo", "bar", "baz")])[last()]
```

I cannot use `contains()` because I need to guard against substring matches. I'm using XPath 1.0 and [an answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12155466/712334) is the impetus for this question.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In XPath 2.0,

```
(//h2[@id = ("foo", "bar", "baz")])[last()]
```

would select the last `h2` element in the document with an `id` attribute value of `foo`, `bar`, or `baz`.

In XPath 1.0, you'd use explicit boolean `or` operators:

```
(//h2[@id="foo" or @id="bar" or @id="baz"])[last()]
```

Comment: And a high-five for providing the XPath 2.0 equivalent. Thanks a million!!