# xpath document evaluate contains this OR that

Tags: javascript, xpath, contains

i want to check if there is a certain string in a document, or another certain string. (and then do something) is it possible to use OR in xpath expressions?
i tried this:

```
var xyz = document.evaluate("//dd[contains(., 'year || month')]", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null );
var xyz = headings.iterateNext();
```

Comment: Can you provide some code? Generally you have to use `or` instead of `||`. Check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12152890/xpath-contains-one-of-multiple-values

Answer (score 1):

As @Pete says; or in XPath 2.0+ you can use a regular expression:

```
//dd[matches(., 'year|month')]
```

(With XPath questions, please ALWAYS say which version you are using, as it very frequently affects the answer, and all versions are in common use.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `or` operator:

```
"//dd[contains(.,'year') or contains(.,'month')]"
```