# xpath: combining multiple filters on same level

Tags: xpath

I'm desperately trying to combining several filters in xpath. Assume my data looks like that:

```
 <Table name="MyTable1">
  <Item>
    <Status date="2015-03-01" category="one/two">DELETE</Status>
    <Old />
    <Current>
      <Field name="ID">1</Field>
      <Field name="Title">This is my title</Field>
      <Field name="Short_title">my short title</Field>
      <Field name="Order">1</Field>
    </Current>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Status date="2015-03-01" category="one/two">EQUAL</Status>
    <Old />
    <Current>
      <Field name="ID">2</Field>
      <Field name="Title">here comes another title</Field>
      <Field name="Short_title">another short one</Field>
      <Field name="Order">2</Field>
    </Current>
  </Item>
</Table>
```

My wish is to access all "Current"-nodes that

- contain **Status category "two"**
- have a **Status which does not
  contain "DELETE"**

I tried to combine several questions asked on stackoverflow:

- [XPATH Multiple Element Filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472966/xpath-multiple-element-filters)
- [How to use not contains() in xpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11024080/how-to-use-not-contains-in-xpath)

For instance one of my queries would have been:

- `/Table/Item[Status[[contains(@category,'two')] AND [not(contains('DELETE')]]/Current`

Any ideas what could be a better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following `XPath` expression:

```
//Status[contains(@category,"two") and not(text()="DELETE")]/following-sibling::Current
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer. You've helped a lot!

Comment: I'm glad to see that it helped

Answer (score 1):

You can just combine two boolean expressions with `and` directly, don't put square brackets around each expression. :

```
/Table/Item[Status[contains(@category,'two') and not(contains(., 'DELETE'))]]/Current
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer. You've helped a lot!